# ¿Cómo recorrer un array dentro de otro array?

Tags: php, laravel, array

Trato de obtener los valores del array de "hermano", la clave es `dinamic` ya intenté con `for` pero no me reconoce:

```
for($l=0;$l<count($pru);$l++) {
              for ($h=0; $h <count($pru[$l]) ; $h++) { 
                dd($pru[$l][$h]);
              }
}
```

Intenté con `foreach` y solo me presenta el primer valor:

```
$pru=array($request->hermano);

for($l=0;$l<count($pru);$l++) {
      foreach ($pru[$l] as  $values) {
       dd($values);
      }

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cómo se llama la variable donde se almacena esa información? ¿Podrías copiar/pegar el contenido de un `var_export` en vez de una captura de pantalla? Gracias.

Comment: la captura de imagen es lo que me trae las respuesta de un formulario dd($request->all());

Comment: El problema es que [`dd()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-dd) finaliza la ejecución de tu script, por lo que sólo saldrá el primer elemento. Por favor, usa `var_export` si no deseas la finalización prematura del programa. Según la exportación, al ser una matriz, deberías usar `$request['hermano']`, pero sin una exportación clara nativa (sin capturas, con copiar/pegar) no te lo puedo confirmar.

Comment: esto me sale con el var_export($request->all());
array (
  '_token' => 'bGJVDLHkRw8jMdsoBvC4ouyBEvgyBs5VLHD8LlDp',
  'oculto' => 'Leonela Burgos ',
  'id_alumno' => '',
  'alumno' => '',
  'cedula_alumno_pres' => '',
  'dir_alumno_pres' => '',
  'telf_alumno_pres' => '',
  'fch_nac_alumno_pres' => '',
  'sex_alum_pres' => '',
  'op_desc_alum' => 'dsc_herm',
  'dato_buscar' => '0101030435',
  'selector' => '2',
  'hermano' => 
  array (
    39 => '39',
    40 => '40',
  ),
  'alumno_fin' => '',
  'cedula_alumno' => '',
  'edc_alumno' => '',
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dada la información que proporcionas la manera de recorrer los valores sería mediante un bucle [`foreach`](http://php.net/control-structures.foreach):

```
/* $datos = $request->all(); */
$datos = [
  '_token' => 'bGJVDLHkRw8jMdsoBvC4ouyBEvgyBs5VLHD8LlDp',
  'oculto' => 'Leonela Burgos ',
  'id_alumno' => '',
  'alumno' => '',
  'cedula_alumno_pres' => '',
  'dir_alumno_pres' => '',
  'telf_alumno_pres' => '',
  'fch_nac_alumno_pres' => '',
  'sex_alum_pres' => '',
  'op_desc_alum' => 'dsc_herm',
  'dato_buscar' => '0101030435',
  'selector' => '2',
  'hermano' => [
    39 => '39',
    40 => '40',
  ],
  'alumno_fin' => '',
  'cedula_alumno' => '',
  'edc_alumno' => '',
];
foreach ($datos['hermano'] as $clave => $valor) {
  echo '<p>', htmlspecialchars($clave . ' => ' . $valor), '</p>', PHP_EOL;
}
```

No puedes recorrer los valores usando [`count()`](http://php.net/count) porque esta función calcula el número de elementos de una matriz. Tu bucle empezaría por 0 y terminaría por 1, impidiendo llegar a las claves donde se almacenan los datos (39 y 40).

Por el contrario `foreach` itera por cada elemento y permite extraer el índice y el contenido de cada elemento.

Comment: ¿Por qué usas `htmlspecialchars`?

Comment: Porque imagino que lo estará usando para ser mostrado en una página web y no sé si siempre los valores son numéricos o no. Mejor asegurarse que ser víctima de XSS.

Comment: La verdad que desconozco los posibles ataques de XSS. Aunque quizá no sea el lugar adecuado, ¿podrías comentar brevemente en este ejemplo cómo se podría ser víctima de XSS si no usas `htmlspecialchars`? ¿O indicar alguna pregunta aquí que trate sobre el tema?

Comment: Es un tema del que tengo pendiente hablar en mi canal de youtube, pero aquí tienes una guía rápida (la fila "HTML Entity Encoding"): [https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Output_Encoding_Rules_Summary](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Output_Encoding_Rules_Summary)

Comment: Muchas gracias, revisaré cuando pueda la información del enlace. El tema ha sido tratado en algunas preguntas aquí, pero no con la profundidad que amerita.

Answer (score 0):

hola alguien me podría ayudar a imprimir de este `array` solo las palabras CLAVE ACCESO REGISTRADA.

```
Array
(
[estado] => DEVUELTA
[comprobantes] => Array
    (
        [comprobante] => Array
            (
                [claveAcceso] => 1403202001050371719100110010010000005260000106910
                [mensajes] => Array
                    (
                        [mensaje] => Array
                            (
                                [identificador] => 43
                                [mensaje] => CLAVE ACCESO REGISTRADA
                                [tipo] => ERROR
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

)
```

Comment: La zona de respuestas no esta para hacer preguntas, puedes crear tu propia pregunta